# Can you keep a Bank of America account with no US phone number?

Tags: usa, banking, relocation

I recently moved to India from the US and have an active Bank of America account in the US. I was able to update my new Indian address as my mailing address in my contact information but I am not able to update the phone number with an Indian number.

I want to stop my US phone number service and hence want to use my Indian number as my contact number. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Might be worth contacting them and seeing what they say. They may not have even considered that the site won't accept international numbers.

Comment: yeah will talk to them, it should be allowed since they accept international mailing address.

Comment: What the solution? Were you allowed to keep account without phone number or had to close the account?

Comment: How did you change the bank and transfer the money while being outside US ? Customer care is having wait time for more than 15-20 min.s and it has become highly impossible to connect to them.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried it myself and it doesn't look like you can. I guess BOA doesn't want to possibly incur the cost of international text messages. Or, perhaps more likely, they simply haven't done the IT work needed to account for non-US phone numbers yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have talked to B of A about entering a foreign number for my US account. They will not allow it so I move my money to another bank.